# trying to understand LD_PRELOAD and SUID/SGID with checkinstall or porg

Tags: setuid, ld-preload, linux-from-scratch, checkinstall

I want to use [porg](http://porg.sourceforge.net/) in my [LFS](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/) distro. It's similar to [checkinstall](http://checkinstall.izto.org/), it uses `LD_PRELOAD`.

**1**. If you read the [README](http://checkinstall.izto.org/docs/README):

> CheckInstall currently is unable to track any file system changes made
>   by  statically linked programs

I think it refers to the commands like `mkdir`, `mv`, `ln`, etc. So I should not have any problems with this. Am I right?

**2**. Then, the main problem:

> NOTE ON SUID/SGID PROGRAMS: CheckInstall can't track their actions
>   because of  some limitations in the LD_PRELOAD system that
>   installwatch uses. This is   good for security reasons, but it can
>   generate unexpected results when  the installation process uses
>   SUID/SGID binaries.

What does it mean? I don't care if I lose track of some files. I do care if there will be unexpected results, or if I can't install correctly the package.

Also, how many packages have this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In case coreutils (`mkdir`, `mv`, etc. ) on your system  are statically linked (i.e. running `file` on them reports "statically linked") `porg` will not be able to track their operations and thus some installed files may go untracked. Statically linked executables are second-class citizens in Linux and `LD_PRELOAD` does not support them.
2. Setuid executables indeed sanitize `LD_PRELOAD` before usage - they ignore all files which have slashes in name (so that only files from standard system paths can be loaded) and also require that shared library itself has setuid bit set. So in your case you'll need to locate `porg`'s preloaded library and set setuid bit on it (via `chmod a+s libxyz.so`). BTW it may make sense to ask `porg` authors to do this change in their distro. I don't think this will cause any problems in a typical package as installers typically don't need to run setuid programs (like `mount`, `passwd`, `sudo`).